# Problems while trying to replace a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tuples, python-itertools

I have the following lists of tuples:

```
list1 = [('the', 'a'), ('over','1'), ('quick','b'),('fox', 'c'), ('brown', 'd'), ('dog','e'), ('jumps','2')]
```

I am trying to replace some tuples as follows (*):

```
('the', 'a') -> ('the', 'ART')
('quick','b') -> ('quick','VERB')
('fox', 'c') -> ('fox', 'ANIMAL')
```

In other words, the tuples of `list1`, should be replaced like this:

```
list1 = [('the', 'ART'), ('over','1'), ('quick','VERB'),('fox', 'ANIMAL'), ('brown', 'd'), ('dog','e'), ('jumps','2')]
```

So, I tried with the following function:

```
def replace_val(alist, key, value):
    return [(k,v) if (k != key) else (key, value) for (k, v) in alist]
```

The problem is that I can't pass all the new tuples from (*) in one movement, I must do:

```
replace_val(list1, 'the', 'ART')
replace_val(list1, 'quick', 'VERB')
replace_val(list1, 'fox', 'ANIMAL')
```

Thus, my question is: How can I replace efficiently in one movement all the new tuples from (*) in order to get?:

```
[('the', 'ART'), ('over','1'), ('quick','VERB'),('fox', 'ANIMAL'), ('brown', 'd'), ('dog','e'), ('jumps','2')]
```

Comment: You could use dictionaries instead of list of tuples, if your key is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would help.

```
list1 = [('the', 'a'), ('over','1'), ('quick','b'),('fox', 'c'), ('brown', 'd'), ('dog','e'), ('jumps','2')]
list2 = [('the', 'a'), ('over','1'), ('quick','b'),('fox', 'c'), ('brown', 'Dog'), ('dog','e'), ('jumps','2')]
z=(dict(dict(list1),**dict(list2)).items())
print(z)
```

**[DEMO](https://repl.it/Eo7y)**

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [('the', 'a'), ('over','1'), ('quick','b'),('fox', 'c'), ('brown', 'd'), ('dog','e'), ('jumps','2')]
dict1 = dict(list1)
print(dict1)
dict1['the'] = 'ART'
dict1['quick'] = 'VERB'
dict1['fox'] = 'ANIMAL'
print(dict1)
list2 = [i for i in dict1.items()]
# or
list2 = list(dict1.items())

print(list2)
```

out:

```
{'the': 'a', 'fox': 'c', 'brown': 'd', 'dog': 'e', 'quick': 'b', 'jumps': '2', 'over': '1'}
{'the': 'ART', 'fox': 'ANIMAL', 'brown': 'd', 'dog': 'e', 'quick': 'VERB', 'jumps': '2', 'over': '1'}
[('the', 'ART'), ('fox', 'ANIMAL'), ('brown', 'd'), ('dog', 'e'), ('quick', 'VERB'), ('jumps', '2'), ('over', '1')]
```

Comment: Woops, apparently this was by far a better solution.

Comment: You could do `list(dict1.items())` instead of list comprehension

Comment: Which is faster?.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the simple and plain way, here is one:

```
>>> list1 = [('the', 'a'), ('over','1'), ('quick','b'),('fox', 'c'), ('brown', 'd'), ('dog','e'), ('jumps','2')]
>>> 
>>> list2 = [('the', 'ART'), ('quick', 'VERB'), ('fox', 'ANIMAL')]
>>> 
>>> list3 = []
>>> d1 = dict(list1)
>>> d2 = dict(list2)
>>> 
>>> for k in d1:
        if k not in d2:
            list3.append((k, d1[k]))
        else :
            list3.append((k, d2[k]))


>>> list3
[('jumps', '2'), ('dog', 'e'), ('brown', 'd'), ('the', 'ART'), ('fox', 'ANIMAL'), ('over', '1'), ('quick', 'VERB')]
```

Creating a dictionary from your list of tuples will make lookup along both lists very quick and easy, then all you have to do is take the corresponding values matching your search criteria.